# Django ORM and displaying many to many fields in template

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, orm, jinja2

I am having trouble displaying data from a many-to-many field on my template.

My models looks like so:

```
class User(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField()
password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Secret(models.Model):
message = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
all_likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="all_users")
objects = SecretManager()
```

When a user clicks a like button, the user is associated with the secret via the all_likes field.

In my template, I am displaying all secrets, then a "delete" button if the session ID is equal to the posted_by user ID. Now all I'm trying to do is add the text "you liked this" if the secret's all_likes contains the user, but nothing i'm doing is right.

```
   <table>
     {% if secrets %}
        {% for secret in secrets %} 
        <tr>
            <td>{{secret.message}}</td>
            <td>{{secret.created_at}}</td>
            {% if request.session.id == secret.posted_by.id %}
            <td>You posted this</td>
            <td> <form action="{%url 'secrets:delete_secret' id=secret.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
                </form>
            {% endif %}
            {% if request.session.id != secret.posted_by.id %}
            <td> <form action="{%url 'secrets:create_like' user_id=request.session.id secret_id=secret.id %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="submit" name="Like" value="Like">
                </form>
            {% endif %}
////HERE I WANT TO ADD LOGIC TO DiSPLAY "YOU LIKED THIS" IF REQUEST.SESSION.ID IS EQUAL TO SECRET.ALL_LIKES.USER.ID////
             </td>
         </tr>
        {% endfor %} 
     {% endif %}
  </table>
```

How do I do this seemingly simple task?

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom method in Secret class and decorate it as a property as below

```
@property
def all_like_ids(self):
  return [x.id for x in self.all_likes]
```

Then in your template do :

```
{%if request.session.id in secret.all_like_ids %}

{%endif%}
```

Comment: `@cached_property` would be better here.